# Java security manager startNetworService not running

Tags: java, derby

I am trying to run derby from command prompt. While i run startNetworService.bat  i get the following error

[image]

I did few google search and found that the following code has to be added to java.policy file

```
grant {

permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen,resolve";
};
```

I still am not able to run derby on my pc. I have check environment for java and derby and it all looks fine to me too.

Expecting someone can help me here. 
Cheers Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running the command prompt as admin?? I know it sounds too simple but it looks like Java doesn't have permission to listen on a ServerSocket

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for running the Derby Network Server with a Java Security Manager: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/tadminnetservrun.html